Defining SI unit: Using brackets while using ensuremath=\cdot and avoiding fractions; Spacing between multiplication dot (\cdot) and units in \unit{}
this question has two parts, and I'm not sure whether one of them has been answered in a different thread before, so please excuse me if that is the case.
I'm trying to define a relatively long unit via the \DefineSIunit command within the \siuntix package (using Overleaf, TeX Live version 2023).
The unit should in the end look like the following:

Meaning, that the N.m should be in brackets as the denominator of the fraction, but using multiplicator points and the negative exponent.
I've been able to simply code it out by hand:
\unit[inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]{\mm^3.(\N.\m)^{-1}}

But since it is a common unit and often recurring within my manuscript, I wanted to define it in the preamble to use a shorter code, such as \unit{\wear} throughout the text.
My initial try was this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\DeclareSIUnit[inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]\wear{\cubic\milli\metre\per\newton\per\metre}
\begin{document}
  Here is some text with the result 0.5\,\unit{\wear}
  The unit should however more look like this 
\unit[inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]{\mm^3.(\N.\m)^{-1}}

\end{document}

Adding brackets within the \DefineSIunit renders the code for some reason useless and the only output is ()
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\DeclareSIUnit[inter-unit-product = 
\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]\wear{\cubic\milli\metre\per(\newton\per\metre)}

\begin{document}
 
 Another example is this 0.5\,\unit{\wear}
  
\end{document}

How would I be able to fix this? I am aware that using per-mode = symbol would put the second part into brackets, but would use the slash instead of the negative exponent to indicate the fraction.
Second part of the question: I would like to have a smaller space between the individual unit parts and the multiplication dot. but using \, anywhere within the \DefineSIunit did not yield any result. I've tried adding it within the
[inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]
but nothing seemed to have an effect there. This spacing question would also apply in the case of using the long hand-coded version of the unit.
Thank you all in advance for your help, really appreciate it!

The approach taken by siunitx is that units are all of equal 'weight', meaning that things like mm^{3}.(N.m)^{-1} don't really fit into that (though I do have an open feature request in this area). If you want the output exactly as you describe, you can do it by hard-coding a suitable 'unit' - but then you need to do all of the decision making about appearance
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\DeclareSIUnit\wear{mm^{3}\mathord\cdot(N\mathord\cdot m)^{-1}}

\begin{document}
 
 Another example is this 0.5\,\unit{\wear}
  
\end{document}

In particular, . is only interpreted as an inter-unit marker when the unit info is read directly, not if you've saved as a single 'unit'.

I will bear in mind the idea of some form of per-mode = power-bracket-negative or similar, but no promises on when I might add it :)

I understand, thank you.
The version with the . in it was only used within the text itself when I hand-coded the unit. As I understand your code, you're essentially not "coding" the individual parts of the unit as actual unit functions but simply as text?
This apparently also fixes the second part of my question about spacing between the parts of the resulting unit. Is there another option though, in any other case, to adjust the spacing around \cdot within a declared unit?
